# Android ExpandableListView disable group click effect

Tags: android, styles, expandablelistview

When I'm clicking on the item the default selectable style is orange background.

I **don't** want this effect on group header click.

`android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"` it's not a good idea because it will effect also on the sub-items.

There's any way to do it without changing the default ExpandableListView style?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting a color to the selector set a background shape such as custom_shape.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
```

... and in your xml it would be:

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/custom_shape"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: very much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Set only transparent color in listSelector....Working fine

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```